# Telnet send string by character

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, telnet, wireshark

I wrote code can send a message to server. Problem is if I capture communication in Wireshark my string message sent from my application looks like this:

```
hello    - 1 packet
```

If I check the same message sent from Telnet cmd terminal message looks like this:

```
h      - 1 packet
e      - 1 packet
l      - 1 packet
l      - 1 packet
o      - 1 packet
```

So finally it sent entire string by character. Server can read the message from cmd Telnet terminal and reply but can't read the message sent from my application. Is there some way how can I send string like this? I'm not programming server. I'm programming only client side so it's important server has to able read the message correctly. Thanks a lot!

```
PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;

 public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);

                    // create a socket to make the connection with the server
                    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
                    Log.i("Terminal", "Socket connecting");

                    try {

                        // send the message to the server
                        out = new PrintWriter(
                                new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                                        socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                        Log.i("Terminal", "Connected.");
                        // receive the message which the server sends back
                        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                socket.getInputStream()));

                     }catch...
               }catch...
 }

//send code
public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
            out.println(message);
            out.flush();
            Log.i("Terminal", "Message sent.");
        }
}
```

Comment: Please define "can't read the message sent from my application". The server cannot distinguish these two cases. You must be doing something else wrong, for example incorrect or absent line termination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just send each character separately?

Something like this:

```
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    for (String ch : message.split(""))
        sendPacket(ch);
    sendPacket("\r\n");
}

public void sendPacket(String payload) {
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        out.print(payload);
        out.flush();
        Log.i("Terminal", "Message sent.");
    }
}
```

You said everything was working fine, but if you do run in to issues with packet coalescing in the future you can disable the Nagle algorithm by adding this line:

```
socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
```

right after this one:

```
socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port);
```

Comment: This code will send just every char separately but it will not put together all string in serverside. Like this: [link](http://clip2net.com/s/6Wsf4r)

Comment: I modified it a little bit. Before it was sending each character and a newline, now it only sends a newline after sending all the characters. Try it now and see if it works.

Comment: I think problem is that server side is still received just chars and server doesn't know all chars together form one message.

Comment: @MikeB You fixed one minor thing. You didn't fix the major thing that is inherently wrong with this answer, which completely invalidates it.

Comment: @EJP The OP wanted his code to work like telnet. Telnet is also subject to the same TCP packet coalescing, is it not? So if the server he is communicating with works fine with telnet, why wouldn't it work fine with the code I've posted here? (Hint: According to the OP himself, it does work fine with the code I've posted here)

Comment: @MikeB Because, as I said, TCP will coalesce outgoing packets unless the Nagle algorithm is disabled. It is clear from what the OP posted that either Telnet is disabling the Telnet algorithm or he is typing with more than the 200ms Nagle timeout between keystrokes into Telnet. This code doesn't do either of those things and will therefore not produce the desired effect. You seem to be claiming that Telnet does the same as your code above. All you need is evidence.

Comment: @EJB Meh, it worked for the OP, that was the whole purpose of the question. I think it speaks volumes about you that instead of providing the fix for the problem you imagined the OP was having (that he wasn't actually having) you chose to argue that the solution I provided wouldn't work. But it did work. If your goal was to stroke your own ego and demonstrate your superior knowledge, congratulations, mission accomplished. If your goal was to advance the community then I'm afraid you failed miserably.