# Telnet late server reply

Tags: java, networking, telnet

I have very strange problem with telnet communication. When I send a message to server, server will reply every time after next message. Server reply looks like this:

> // bad IP transmitters adress message

If I send "first message" server will not reply. After I send "second message" server will reply to the first message. Every time reply from server is one message late. 
My communication looks like this:

[image]

If I use Telnet application from Google Play Store it works perfect and communication looks like this:

```
 C: first message
 S: [// bad IP transmitters adress message 'first message']
 C: second message
 S: [// bad IP transmitters adress message 'second message']
 C: third message
 S: [// bad IP transmitters adress message 'third message']
```

Is there some way how fix it? Thank you so much!

Code:

TCPclass

```
public class TCPclass {

private boolean mRun = false;
String messageFromServer;
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
PrintWriter out;
BufferedReader in;

public TCPclass(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

public void stopClient() {
    mRun = false;
}

public void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
        message = message + '\r' + '\n';
        out.print(message);
        out.flush();
        Log.i("Terminal", "Message sent.");
    }
}

public void start(String hostname, int port) {
    mRun = true;
    try {
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);

        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port);

        try {

            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            // receive the message which the server sends back
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

            while (mRun) {
              do
              {

               String messageFromServer = in.readLine();


                if (messageFromServer != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(messageFromServer); //append message to Text View
                }
                messageFromServer = null;


             } while (in.ready());
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Terminal", "S: Error ", e);
        } finally {
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Terminal", "Establish connection error " + hostname + " "
                + port);
    }
}

public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}
}
```

MainActivity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TCPclass mTcpClass;
public String hostname = "127.0.0.1";
public int port = 7011;
TextView serverMessage;
private connectTask mTask;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText IPaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eAddress);
    final EditText ePort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ePort);
    final EditText eMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eMessage);
    serverMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tOutput);

    Button okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOK); //Connect button
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) { // connect
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            hostname = IPaddress.getText().toString(); 
            String strPort = ePort.getText().toString(); 

            try {
                port = Integer.parseInt(strPort); 

            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.e(strPort, "Error port");
            }
            mTask = new connectTask();
            mTask.execute("");
        }
    });

    Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSend);
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String message = eMessage.getText().toString();
            serverMessage.append("C: " + message + "\n");
            Log.i("Terminal", "Sending message " + message);
            if (mTcpClass != null) {
                mTcpClass.sendMessage(message);
            }
            eMessage.setText("");
        }
    });
}

public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TCPclass> {
    @Override
    protected TCPclass doInBackground(String... message) {
        Log.i("Terminal", "doInBackground.");

        mTcpClass = new TCPclass(new TCPclass.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            // here the messageReceived method is implemented
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                // this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClass.start(hostname, port);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        serverMessage.append("S: " + Arrays.toString(values) + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown any of your receiving code, and I'm guessing buffering there.

Comment: I added the code to my question. Please take a look. Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using this discredited `sendPacket()` code from your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22158475/207421)? It doesn't do what the author claimed for it.

Comment: ok I added full code.
@EJP I added there '\r' and now it is working just server reply every time one message late. Before I asked previous question server did not respond at all.

Comment: @I'm not talking about the `\r,` although that should certainly be `\r\n` as per the RFC, unless you've negotiated binary mode in Telnet. I'm talking about the stupid technique of sending a character at a time via the `sendMessage()` and `sendPacket()` methods and pretending, as the author was, that TCP won't re-coalesce them again. `sendMessage()` should just append `\r\n` and call `print()` and `flush()` directly.

Comment: @EJP Please give me sec I will change it to your advice and see if it works.

Comment: @EJP I edited code now I'm using. The effect is still the same. Server response is every time one message late.
`public void sendMessage(String message) {
  if (out != null && !out.checkError()) {
   message = message + '\r' + '\n';
   out.print(message);
   out.flush();
   Log.i("Terminal", "Message sent.");
  }
 }`

Comment: I'm not attempting to answer *this* question, I'm just trying to help you clean up your code and remove a misapprehension.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the server is probably sending a blank or extra line somewhere that you haven't accounted for. I'm the world's last and least fan of calling `available()` or `ready()` but maybe this is a case for it:

```
do
{
    String response = in.readLine();
    // ...
} while (in.ready());
```

... at least for debugging purposes, until you sort out exactly what the response is to each line you send. Note that using a `while` loop here would be definitely incorrect.

Comment: Still the same effect and it looks there is no blank or extra line more. I captured server message from wireshark and it looks like this: http://clip2net.com/s/6XO82z in data there is just message bad ip for 12345 and 0d = (CR)

Comment: It's curious that the response ends with \r (0xd) not \r\n. Can you edit the current code into your question?

Comment: I uploaded.  Hope I used your debugging code correct.

Comment: It looks OK, although if readLine() returns null you should close the connection and exit the reading loop. Can you try it with '\r'?

Comment: Btw. If I delete flush() in code server will reply 2 messages late.  Maybe this fact will also help

Comment: Its the same with /r. I captured also communication telnet_terminal  and server.  Terminal sent every letter in one packet and in last packet sent 0d 0a (/r/n).

Comment: Dunno about the flush. Maybe you should send a blank line first?

Comment: OK. Are you sure you aren't sending blank lines? IOW are you sure that `message` doesn't already have a line terminator on it?

Comment: yes I'm sure. I can see it on wireshark.  There is nothing more in message except 0x0d.